# Exluding certain values from a data set from analysis in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am still rather new to R, so even if this question (or one similar) has been previously asked, I seem unable to find it.

In my assignment, I want to run an OLS regression on a set of values: Age, gender, partisanship, and 2005 election turnout on opinion on a certain topic (e5). Thus, I do the following:

```
PolReg <- lm(Data$e5 ~ Data$age + Data$gender + Data$f1 + Data$turnout05)
```

However, the variable e5 is a survey question, with answers Completely Disagree to Completely Agree as values 1 - 5. In addition to this, there is 98 and 99, which represent Don't Know and Prefer not to Say, respectively.

They will affect the coefficients, and so I need to exclude these values from my regression (or data altogether, if that works better). As far as I can remember, the below would work for removing an entire row from consideration:

```
NULL <- Data$RowName
```

But I cannot seem to adapt this to my purposes. Does anyone know a way to exlude only the "98" and "99" values?

Comment: Something like `subset(data,e5 >= 1 & e5 <= 5)` ?

Comment: You can set the data argument in the lm call: `PolReg <- lm(e5 ~ age + gender + f1 + turnout05, data = subset(Data, !e5 %in% c(98, 99))`.

Comment: First, ensure `e5` is a categorical variable. i.e. `data$e5=factor(data$e5)`.

Comment: Oh yes it's cateorical. I think linear regression is not the right method for this as it is designed for continuous variables. Have a look at ordinal logistic regession for example.

Comment: Thank you, @kath! Am I right, then, in assuming that "!e5" would mean something along the lines of "exclude from this variable the following"?

Answer (score 0):

There is a subset argument within the 'lm' function to handle these situations, while leaving the original data set intact. This should do the trick:

```
PolReg <- lm(e5 ~ age + gender + f1 + turnout05, data = Data, subset = (e5 <= 5))
```